# Improper integrals Question

Tags: improper-integrals

I was asked to define the next intergrals and I want to know if I did it right:
$$1) \int^\infty_a f(x)dx = \lim_{b \to \infty}\int^b_af(x)dx$$
$$2) \int^b_{-\infty} f(x)dx = \lim_{a \to -\infty}\int^b_af(x)dx$$
$$3) \int^\infty_{-\infty} f(x)dx = \lim_{b \to \infty}\int^b_0f(x)dx + \lim_{a \to -\infty}\int^0_af(x)dx$$
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you did.${}$

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, such as Fourier transformation, it is critical that we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^{a} dx \, f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

The first two definitions you gave are the standard definitions, for $f$ say continuous everywhere. The third is more problematical, It is quite possible that the *definition* in your course is
$$\lim_{a\to-\infty, b\to \infty} \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$ 
So $a\to-\infty$, $b\to\infty$ **independently**.

What you wrote down would then be a *fact* rather than a definition.